# How to handle nested resources/routes correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-routes

I am trying to build a Rails app modded from [Michael Hartl's Railstutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book). The code is located on [GitHub](https://github.com/maasha/sporenstregs).

I am using the following nested resources:

```
resources :users do
  resources :scaffolds
end
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `scaffolds_path' for #<#    <Class:0x007f87848019d0>:0x007f8782651948>):
4: 
5: <div class="row">
6:   <div class="span6 offset3">
7:     <%= form_for(@scaffold) do |f| %>
8:       <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
9:       <%= f.text_field :name,        placeholder: "Scaffold name" %>
10:       <%= f.text_area  :description, placeholder: "Description" %> 
app/views/scaffolds/new.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_scaffolds_new_html_erb___1119296061714080468_70109999031900'
```

I am puzzled why it is looking for `scaffolds_path` and not `user_scaffolds_path`?

The `@scaffold` is created in the app/controller/scaffolds_controller.rb:

```
def new
  @scaffold = current_user.scaffolds.build
end
```

Inspecting the `@scaffold` object thus created shows:

```
'#<Scaffold id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, tax_id: nil, user_id: 36, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>'
```

Dumping the methods of `@scaffold` don't reveal any `scaffolds_path` or `user_scaffolds_path` methods which suggest additional problems?

The users model `has_many :scaffolds` and the scaffold model `belongs_to :user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the missing methods is that `form_for` in the view are not aware we are nesting. This is fixed by feeding it an array:

```
form_for([@user, @scaffold])
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the form helper. IF you're using nested resources and you **never** want to perform controller actions on `Scaffold` objects directly, then you need to do the following in your form view and model. Something like:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :scaffolds
end
```

...and in the view...

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= fields_for @user.scaffold do |scaffold_fields| %>
```

...this will result in the path for the `fields_for` giving you the expected `users_scaffolds_path`

NOTE that the specifics of how you use the `fields_for` helper changes depending on whether it's a `has_one` or `has_many` relationship and such. The first time through this you may just tear your hair out - so fair warning.

#### If, on the other hand...

...you want to use `Scaffold` objects on their own **and** as part of a nested route, you can declare the route twice - once for when you want to use it as a nested resource, and once when you want to use it on its own.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :users do
  resources :scaffolds
end

resources :scaffolds
```

With this, when you run `rake routes` you'll see both `users_scaffolds_path` and `scaffolds_path` for all the standard actions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I am doubting, if I should use nested resources at all. I was planning on three levels of nesting, because I wanted an index page for all three levels. According to this: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources I should not nest, but it also says, that it will allow me to show an index at the three levels.

Comment: It's certainly a complexity tradeoff, especially at the view level.

Comment: OK, I just reintroduced nested resources as they are a perfect fit to my design. Also, I found the reason to the missing method as per my auto answer.